# reading api fields

Tags: lightning, api

I have an api response as follows

```
[
  {
    "providerInfo": {
      "pcd_eligible": false,
      "tiered_plan": true,
      "tiers": {
        "provider_tier": 2,
        "benefit_tier": 2
      }
    },
"providerInfo": {
      "pcd_eligible": false,
      "tiered_plan": true,
      "tiers": {
        "provider_tier": 1,
        "benefit_tier": 1
      }
    }
]
```

After reading the response, if provider_tier = 1, then I want to change the api response as provider_tier" = "Maximum"
similarly if provider_tier" = 2, then I want to change the api response as provider_tier = "Standard"
sp api after changes will look like this
providerInfo":

```
{
      "pcd_eligible": false,
      "tiered_plan": true,
      "tiers": {
        "provider_tier": "Maximum",
        "benefit_tier": 1
      }
    }
var providerList = component.get("v.providerList");
```

variable providerList will have the initial api response.

```
for(var list=0;list<providerList.length;list++){
if(providerList[list].providerInfo.tiers.provider_tier.toString() === 1){
                    providerList[list].providerInfo.tiers.provider_tier = 'Maximum';
            }
            else if(providerList[list].providerInfo.tiers.provider_tier.toString() === 2){
                    providerList[list].providerInfo.tiers.provider_tier = "Standard";
}
```

But I am unable to change api field values. Please let me know how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is always a best practice to provide what errors you received, or if you didn't receive any. Thank you Sachin for the Edit.

From what I understand, your use case is straightforward, but the statements where you are making changes are not getting executed ?

Looking at the snippet, I see a flaw in the If condition :

```
if(providerList[list].providerInfo.tiers.provider_tier.toString() === 1)
```

Here the LHS is "provider_tier" and the data type is "String". The RHS is 1 and the data type is Integer. This condition will result in "False", due to type mismatch.

Try the below snippet :

```
if(providerList[list].providerInfo.tiers.provider_tier === 1)
//OR
if(providerList[list].providerInfo.tiers.provider_tier.toString() === '1')
```

Let me know if this works for you !

Comment: @pramod, thanks, that worked